# Django InlineFormsets with programm logic or multiple use-Inlines?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In my use-case I have 3 models, a `house`, `room` and `chair`.
They are all intuitively in a 1:many-realtionship.
I want to *reuse* the inline on the `house` model to be used for 2 (consecutive) operations.

When I save a `house` I want to add `rooms` to it, and for each `room` the number of chairs that would fit each individual `room`¸ 
Once I created the `house` with its `rooms`, I want to add `chairs` to each `room`, but not more then the number of chairs that would fit into those individual rooms.

For convenience I'd like to use one Inline for adding rooms and setting the max number of chairs. I'd then like to use that Inline to assign chairs to the given `house`-`rooms`.
I want to do those 2 operations while staying on 1 (web)page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *max_num* option directly inside the inline.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num):

> This controls the maximum number of forms to show in the inline. This doesn’t directly correlate to the number of objects, but can if the value is small enough. See Limiting the number of editable objects for more information.

More info here: [Limiting the number of editable objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects)

Comment: I don't want to limit the number of models shown in an inline. I want to 'reuse' the inline. I edited my question to make that more clear. sry if it was confusing at first. But thanks.